# A good method to detect any(not just malicious) intentionally obfuscated urls in text

Tags: c#, url, artificial-intelligence, detection

I have a website on which anyone can register and post public content. However certain malicious users go on the site and post links that have to be legally taken down.
So all new users have to be approved before they can post URLs.
However, they attempt to avoid URL detection, like posting URLs similar to these:

h tt.pp//example(dot)com

Mainly URL shorteners and image hosting sites are the problems.

I would like to use a one-time solution.

Our URL detection method is continuously advanced to counter their obfuscation attempts. It uses regex and replaces techniques and blacklisting of known sites that the malicious users can/have used, but there are too many to blacklist them all.

I have looked into AI solutions, but I can't find one that seems good for my problem, as most AI's are dedicated to detecting phishing sites, instead of obfuscated URLs.
Another option is to train our own AI, but this would take us more time(we have not done this before) to workout then continuously advance the URL detector as we do now.

As a last resort, we may try to train an AI ourselves, suggestions where to find suitable data for this, are also appreciated.

We use C#, but any language is an option, we will integrate it one way or another.

```cs
public static class SecurityHelper
{
    private static string UrlCheckerReplaceRegex;
    private static string UrlCheckerBadStringsRegex;
    private static string UrlCheckerBadStringsSpaceRegex;

    static SecurityHelper()
    {
        var repalceStrings = new string[] { @"\s", "-", @"\[", @"\]", @"\(", @"\)", @"\{", @"\}", "d+o*t+", @"/", @"\\", @"\|", "d*o+t+", "d+o+t+", @"\." };
        Array.ForEach(repalceStrings, (str) => str = '(' + str + ')');
        UrlCheckerReplaceRegex = string.Join("|", repalceStrings);

        var badStrings = new string[]
        {
            @"u\.*to\.+", @"goo\.+gl"
        };
        Array.ForEach(badStrings, (str) => str = '(' + str + ')');
        UrlCheckerBadStringsRegex = string.Join("|", badStrings);

        var badStringsSpace = new string[]
        {
            "ww+", "h+t+p+", "imgur", "sh4re", "ibb", @"bitly", @"tinyurl", @"cuttly", @"demopolrme", @"doiopcom",
            @"tinycc", @"[0-9]ly", @"shrunkencom", @"[0-9]gp", @"pasia", @"gasia", @"gggg", @"bitdo", @"isgd", @"vgd",
            @"tnysh", @"tinypic", @"0rztw", @"chilpit"
        };
        Array.ForEach(badStringsSpace, (str) => str = '(' + str + ')');
        UrlCheckerBadStringsSpaceRegex = string.Join("|", badStringsSpace);
    }

    public static bool ContainsPossibleUrls(string text)
    {
        var modifiedText = text.ToLower();
        modifiedText = Regex.Replace(modifiedText, string.Join("|", UrlCheckerReplaceRegex), ".");
        // replace all spaces and other characters to get the unobfuscated text and try and find a blacklisted url, here they are replaced by a '.', because some blacklisted urls are too broad and we do not want to accidently block a non malicious input (www\u.to\, 'u to' can be matched if someone writes 'u too' as part of a message, so we look for "u\.*to\.+")

        if (Regex.Match(modifiedText, UrlCheckerBadStringsRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success)
        {
            return true;
        }

        var modifiedTextSpace = text.ToLower();
        modifiedTextSpace = Regex.Replace(modifiedTextSpace, string.Join("|", UrlCheckerReplaceRegex), "");
        // remove all spaces and other characters to get the unobfuscated text and try and find a blacklisted url

        if (Regex.Match(modifiedTextSpace, UrlCheckerBadStringsSpaceRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (FindUrls(text).Count > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static List<string> FindUrls(string text)
    {
        var urls = new List<string>();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        {
            return urls;
        }

        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"(http|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])?"); // find all urls
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            foreach (Capture capture in match.Captures)
            {
                urls.Add(capture.Value);
            }
        }

        return urls.Distinct().ToList();
    }
}
```

If a human mind can identify the pattern of the URL, then an AI must be able to as well.

Comment: Have a look at this related discussion: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/215871/redacting-urls-as-an-email-phishing-preventative

Comment: Thank you for the link, but the problem is not like an email phishing attack, which is why I have trouble finding a good solution, such as an AI already trained to do this.
Users will know not to open these links, they just need to not stay up for public viewing, as they link to illegal contents.

The link you provided says people will be able to go around any filter, but I believe an AI can stop it. Because if a human can detect link patterns, then you can create an AI to detect the same patterns.

Comment: The problem is that a human can think of a new pattern that an AI agent will not detect until you train it to do that. And that is the point where you are starting again an arms race that you can not win.